# Committing a docker data volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    db: 
        # standard postgres
    php:
        build: 
          context: ./
          dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile.deploy
        image: registry.gitlab.com/xxx/php:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
        volumes:
            - symfonydata:/var/www/symfony

    nginx:
        build: ./docker/nginx
        image: registry.gitlab.com/xxx/nginx:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes_from:
            - php
        links:
            - php
volumes: 
    symfonydata:
```

In the php-Dockerfile, I add my php code **to the volume** like:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

COPY . /var/www/symfony/
WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
```

Ok this works, after `docker-compose build` I can run

```
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/xxx/php:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/xxx/db:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/xxx/nginx:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

and deploy to a registry. When pulling and `docker-compose up`, the code is there and can be run.

Now, there are other initialization-related things to be done (but only after all services are running).

So I have to execute

```
docker-compose up
docker exec xxx_php_1 composer install
```

After that I would like to store my changes to the image. However the changes are applied to the volume (libs installed in `vendor`). But the command `docker tag ...` does not affect the volume, I also have no idea how to push the volume to the registry.

Comment: Why don't you add the `composer install` command to the Dockerfile?

Comment: Because the install command tries to access the database which is only available after docker-compose up

Comment: I never needed this, in my cases `composer install` only downloaded/populated the `vendor/` directory with external libraries. How/why does `composer install` access the database?

Comment: my symfony-based project tries to warm the cache, which needs access to the database

Comment: But why do you do this inside `composer install`? Why not as a separate script?